# Deployment of SSRS Report in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, deployment, reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics

I have SQL server 2008 R2 , 2 SSRS Reporting server instances (Dev,Live)
and i want to deploy my reports on these instances from Visual Studio 2010.

these 2 SSRS are connected to AX 2012.

it always deploys on the live instance URL by default without giving me the choice to choose which instance i want to deploy on , my question is how can i choose Reporting server instance when deploying.

i know there's command or rs  script for SQL 2008 ,but didn't find something for sql server 2008 R2.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Solution Configurations drop down allows you to select different environments (Debug, release, etc) and you inside the project properties for the SSRS project you can specify different instances for each configuration.